# strange behaviour of operator && in constexpr context

Tags: c++, tuples, if-constexpr, and-operator

The following code tries to make compile-time decisions based on the last argument passed in a parameter pack. It contains a comparison if the number of parameter-pack arguments is > 0 and then tries to get the last element of it. However, the constructed tuple is accessed at an invalid index which is supposedly bigger than the max tuple index (as the `static_assert` shows).
How is that possible if I do `cnt-1`?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:26,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:26,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%23include+%3Cconcepts%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctuple%3E%0A%23include+%22inttypes.h%22%0A%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename...+Args%3E%0Aauto+foo(Args%26%26...+args)%0A%7B%0A++++auto+tuple+%3D+std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward%3CArgs%3E(args)...)%3B%0A++++constexpr+std::size_t+cnt+%3D+sizeof...(Args)%3B%0A%0A++++if+constexpr+(cnt+%3E+0+%26%26+std::same_as%3Cstd::remove_cvref_t%3Cstd::tuple_element_t%3Ccnt-1,+decltype(tuple)%3E%3E,+int%3E)+%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22last+is+int%5Cn%22)%3B%0A++++%7D+else+%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22last+is+not+int%5Cn%22)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++foo(2)%3B%0A%0A++++foo()%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:gsnapshot,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <concepts>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>


template <typename... Args>
auto foo(Args&&... args)
{
    auto tuple = std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    constexpr std::size_t cnt = sizeof...(Args);

    if constexpr (cnt > 0 && std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<std::tuple_element_t<cnt-1, decltype(tuple)>>, int>) {
        printf("last is int\n");
    } else {
        printf("last is not int\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    foo(2);

    foo();
}
```

Error:

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/tuple: In instantiation of 'struct std::tuple_element<18446744073709551615, std::tuple<> >':
<source>:13:25:   required from 'auto foo(Args&& ...) [with Args = {}]'
<source>:24:8:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/tuple:1357:25: error: static assertion failed: tuple index must be in range
 1357 |       static_assert(__i < sizeof...(_Types), "tuple index must be in range");
      |                     ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/tuple:1357:25: note: the comparison reduces to '(18446744073709551615 < 0)'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/tuple:1359:13: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::_Nth_type<18446744073709551615>'
 1359 |       using type = typename _Nth_type<__i, _Types...>::type;
      |             ^~~~
```

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Edited. I should be more careful when crafting the example

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't about the "AND"-operator, but it about the rvalue operator, no?

Comment: @SimonC there is no "rvalue operator" the question is about `and`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) that stops the rhs from being *evaluated* (having its value computed at runtime) doesn't stop it from being *instantiated* (having template arguments substituted into templates, checking them for validity, all at compile-time).

I don't see any particular reason why it couldn't work the way you expect, it just wasn't added to the language (yet).

As @wohlstad said, `if constexpr` is the solution:

```
if constexpr (cnt > 0)
{
    if constexpr (std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<std::tuple_element_t<cnt - 1, decltype(tuple)>>, int>)
    {
        ...
```

The first `if` *must* be constexpr, while the second only *should* (in your scenario).

Comment: Interesting I didn't think of instantiation happening regardless of choosen path, but that would explain it. Afaik clang has the same behaviour. As for std::same_as you can just use it that way. It's a concept and not a type trait (although based on the type trait you mention).

Comment: @glades Ahh, facepalm. Edited.

Comment: One potential reason for why the rhs needs to be instanciated could be that `operator&&` could be overloaded - and the compiler needs to check if such an overload exists, and for that both the type of lhs and the type of rhs must be known.

Answer (score 3):

You can force the compiler to evaluate the 2nd condition only if `cnt > 0` using [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) (available since c++17) and separating into 2 nested `if`s:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <concepts>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

template <typename... Args>
auto foo(Args&&... args)
{
    auto tuple = std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    constexpr std::size_t cnt = sizeof...(Args);

//-----vvvvvvvvv---------
    if constexpr (cnt > 0)
    {
        if (std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<std::tuple_element_t<cnt - 1, decltype(tuple)>>, int>) {
            printf("last is int\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("last is not int\n");
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    foo(2);
    foo();
}
```

Output:

```
last is int
```

Comment: It does work with two nested if constexpr() but why doesn't it work with && operator?

Comment: I am not sure (Upvoted the qeustion because I think it is a good one). But I thought you might find my answer useful since it does offer a way to achieve what you need.

Comment: Thanks yes I'm going for this of course. I was just curious :)